# Chrome Extension: Replacing Favicons

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, favicon

In my chrome extension, I'm trying to find and then replace a site's favicon with a different favicon. I'm able to find the site's favicon url, but I am stuck on how to actually replace it.

I tried using `chrome.tabs.query` and using it's property of `favIconUrl` but I couldn't get it to work, so I then used a method of getting the site's favicon by going to `https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=exampledomain.com`. This does get the url for the favicon, but I am confused on how to proceed to replace the favicon.

EDIT: included more code

## background.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(colorTabs);

function colorTabs(command)
{
    var url = "https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=";
    var addFaviconUrl;

    if ("left-key-toggle-feature" == command)
    {
        chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs)
        {
            /* favicon url */
            addFaviconUrl = tabs[0].url;
            url += addFaviconUrl;


            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {url: url}, function(response) {});

        })
    }
};
```

## content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    if (request.url)
    {
        var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='shortcut icon']") || document.createElement("link");
        link.type = "image/x-icon";
        link.rel = "shortcut icon";
        link.href = chrome.runtime.getURL("img/red-circle-16.png");   // not working
        //link.href = "https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com";  // works!
        document.getElementsByTagName("head").appendChild(link);
    }
})
```

Comment: You need to execute a *content script* which will replace the `<link>` elements used for favicon in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass url from background.js to contentscript.js using message passing like 
background.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {url: url}, function(response) {});  
});
```

and on Content script you need to replace url like

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.url)
      {
       var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'image/x-icon';
    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
    link.href = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to use your code and it does replace the favicon, although I had to remove document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link) for it to work. Not sure why.

Comment: Following this thought, I tried using chrome.runtime.getURL("/img/red-circle-16.png") to replace the favicon with an image from my extension. While the url that is replaced is a valid url, it does not replace the favicon on the page.

Comment: There can be more than one favicon link tags in DOM. Ensure url is valid by inspecting DOM and open url in new tab. I tried this code on some sites and it replaces favicon correctly.

Comment: Ah got it! There is still a problem when I use chrome.runtime.getURL though.  I did inspect and test the url and it does work. Would there be another reason that runtime.getURL is not working?

Comment: can you post code so that I can figure out what's wrong with it?

Comment: Updated my question above!

Comment: I tried above code with removing appendChild line. It works fine. Just make sure you don't have any error message on console and your image is accecible. Whenever correct href is assigned it should immediately replace favicon.

Comment: AHH I had to use web_accessible_resources and declare "img/red-circle-16.png" so it could be loaded from pages outside of the extension, the console was showing an error message. Thank you so much!!